# Subdomain redirect to my external IP - SSL Certificate not valid

Tags: ssl, redirect, subdomain, certificate, apache2

I am running an local Ubuntu-Server as my cloud. This machine is reachable from the outside via my routers portforwarding. This works fine (via IP). Now i created a subdomain in my existing 1und1 domain and used "domain-redirect", to redirect this subdomain xxx.mydomain.com to my external (static) ip with port, which looks like that: https://ip.ip.ip.ip:2000/nextcloud
This is also working fine (but inputs the IP in the adressbar, instead of xxx.mydomain.com), but the standard ubuntu SSL-Cert is obviously not trustworthy. Thats why i bought a cheap ssl-cert from comodo for my subdomain: xxx.mydomain.com
Then i imported the certificate to my ubuntu server (/etc/ssl/certs...) and corrected the /etc/apache2/sites-availabe/nextcloud.conf
(SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile). This (after apache2 restart) lead to the browser reading the Comodo ssl certificate when browsing to xxx.mydomain.com.

**Problem**: The Comodo Cert is still not trusted (There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).)

Has this something to do with the redirecting process? And if yes, how can i solve it?
Or have i missed something else?

Thanks in advance!

€dit: This is the nextcloud.conf file:

```
Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName          cloud.myDomain.com
DocumentRoot        /var/www/nextcloud

SSLEngine               on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/myComodo.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/myComodo.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/myComodo.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All

 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
 </IfModule>

 SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
 SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud

</Directory>
```

Comment: redirect as ...? does it rewrite the URL from https://sub.domain.tld/ to https://11.22.33.44/ ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can chose between HTTP-Redirect (which i use) and Frame-Redirect (which produces an too many redirects error, so i went with HTTP-Redirect).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably the redirect.

Let's say you use `sub.domain.tld` and you get a certificate for this host.

The second you redirect the visitor to `11.22.33.44` the certificate is no longer "valid", because it was setup to work for (COMMON_NAME) `https://sub.domain.tld` and not `https://11.22.33.44`.

The only real solution would be to work with A/CName records. If you do not have a static IP you could use a free dynamic dns and then setup a CNAME record.

Comment: Thanks! I have a static IP. How to "work with A/CName records"?
My hoster has the following settings for my subdomain:
A/AAAA- und CNAME-Entries, MX-Entries and TXT- / SRV-Entries.

Comment: Simply create an A record pointing to your IP.